# Problem with my loops

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, loop, query-posts, date

I am French. Sorry if i make mistakes. 
I have two problems.

The first, I have a page that shows all paying activities sort by date.
The 'posts_per_page' does not work When I put 10, it shows 8 articles.

[image]

Second problem, I have two templates, one that shows the sports activities, and another that shows the cultural activities.
Sorting works on the cultural page, but not on the sports page. Yet it's the same code, only the name of the loop changes.

[image]
[image]

Anyone know where my mistake comes from?

Comment: `var_dump($upcoming)` after the query is run to verify that all query vars are set correctly and generated SQL looks correct.

Comment: Hi milo, looks correct I don't understand